# How to access a deeply nested JSON property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an object that contains HEX color code coming from API. I am storing it as an `app` in a vuejs app. Example, `const app = {"theme":"{\"color\":\"#186DFFF0\"}"}`. Whenever I am trying to access the color property by `app.theme.color`, I get undefined. When I am doing JSON.parse(app) I am getting `Unexpected token # in JSON at position 1`. Any help on how to get that HEX code and store it in a variable?

```js
const app = {"theme":"{\"color\":\"#186DFFF0\"}"}

console.log(app.theme.color)
```

Comment: The JSON is most likely stringified twice, make sure you haven't done it in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the nested property as well.

```js
const app = {"theme":"{\"color\":\"#186DFFF0\"}"}
const { theme } = app;
const themeParsed = JSON.parse(theme);
console.log(themeParsed.color)
```

This is a pretty unusual structure. I'd suggest changing whatever generates it to have the `theme` value be a plain object, rather than a string.

Comment: Actually, this is coming from API. How to async-await on this?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing how the API is structured

Answer (score 0):

```js
const app = {"theme":"{\"color\":\"#186DFFF0\"}"};

const jsonString = app?.theme;
// returns json string => "{\"color\":\"#186DFFF0\"}"

const object = JSON.parse(jsonString);
// returns object => { color: "#186DFFF0" }

// Get nested color property
const color = object?.color;
// returns string => "#186DFFF0"


// if property "color" doesn't exist in object it gives undefined
console.log(color);
```

Comment: The above code surely got never tested.